# netplan is not concatenating addresses on separate YAML files

Tags: netplan, systemd-networkd

I am trying to set up an additional address in an ethernet interface using netplan. The [man](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-netplan-generate/#lbAF) page for netplan-generate mentions that the sequences for the same key configuration should be concatenated , but the value gets always overriden.

base yaml file in `01-network-all.yaml`:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ---other interfaces---
    eth0:
      addresses: [1.1.1.1/24]
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
```

my new configuration file `02-example.yaml`

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: [2.2.2.2/24]
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
```

Whenever I do a netplan generate/apply and then check back the value, the address is only reported as `2.2.2.2/24`.

The `--debug` output implies that networkd is finding both entries but is not joining them as supposed:

```
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration changed, restarting networkd
DEBUG:eth0 exists in {'eth0': {'addresses': ['1.1.1.1/24']}}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
      - 2.2.2.2/24
  renderer: networkd
```

```
netplan get ethernets.eth0.addresses
- 2.2.2.2/24
```

What is going on here? I checked that the changes are taking effect so it is not netplay failing to apply them. I am using the wrong format? I supposed that a sequence is represented by [].

As a follow up question, is there an easy way of doing this change apart from this way? I thought of retrieving the entry with netplan get, processing it with a shell command ant then appending the new one with netplan set but I'll end with a very dirty shell script.

Comment: Good one. Looks like a bug to me, in either the man page or the generator.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and netplan are you running?  What is the content of `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.network`?  The concatenating works as advertised for me with Ubuntu 22.04 (`netplan.io 0.105-0ubuntu2~22.04.1`) when I just run `netplan --debug generate`.