# Netplan: configuration divided across mutliple config files exhibiting unexplained behaviour

Tags: networking, netplan

Consider the following two netplan files:

```
/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
/etc/netplan/route-ens192.yaml
```

The first file has most of the config, and the intent of the second file is for additional routes for ens192. If the main config file has a single route entry, and the second file has a different single entry, only the route in the first file is applied. If additional routes are added to either file, all routes are successfully applied. Further testing has revealed that the problem manifests when there is an equal number of route entries in each file.

What is the reason for this behaviour and can it be fixed?

```
Ubuntu: 22.04.1 LTS
Netplan: 0.105-0ubuntu2~22.04.1
```

Comment: What Ubuntu / netplan version? I wonder if [netplan is not concatenating addresses on separate YAML files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456203/netplan-is-not-concatenating-addresses-on-separate-yaml-files) is related?

Comment: Apologies for not including the version; added now. That question you linked may be another manifestation of the bug, but it's hard to tell at a superficial glance... it does feel like a bug, but looks like nothing has been reported yet. Routes aren't the same as a concatenation of a address list, but route entries are; it could be the same underlying root cause.

Comment: It is a bug.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/2003061 . Unfortunately, I do not see any workaround to the bug.  The bug is specific to routes.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewLowther, I now wonder how I didn't find that bug during my search. I'm not sure how this will affect systems with multiple interfaces; I have servers with up to 8 interfaces. Hopefully a patch will be released soon.